# Check if an image is rasterized

Tags: acrobat

Can someone please tell me how I can check if an image is rasterized using Adobe Acrobat Pro?

Comment: This sounds off-topic. Are you asking how to use Acrobat to check if an image is rasterized, or how to check if an image was rasterized by Acrobat?

Comment: So, the file was probably never created as a tiff or png (because I am not seeing such info). The file is a .pdf file and opens in acrobat only. I am interested in knowing how I can use Adobe Pro to identify rasterization on a document.

Comment: This is not directly related to programming, so this question is better suited to http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

**From within Acrobat** right-click the image in question and select "Properties":
[image: Right-click image to see properties]

If you can't tell by the image description in properties... in the left-hand menu is the image type descriptor. In this pane you can see this image was originally TIFF. Any image format (jpg,gif,tiff,png) will be considered 'raster'.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How do I know this if the image is a pdf file?

Comment: I asked the question wrong. So, the file was probably never created as a tiff or png (because I am not seeing such info). The file is a .pdf file and opens in acrobat only. I am interested in knowing how I can use Adobe Pro to identify rasterization on a document.

Comment: These directions are from *within* the adobe acrobat program.